# nginx use dynamic extracted capture group as location matches

Tags: nginx

I have a simple rule that allow me have multiples static sites on the same nginx server by using subdomains everything works nice

When you call projecta.domain.com the folder /var/www/static/projecta is served
When you call projectb.domain.com the folder /var/www/static/projectb is served

Now I need to add expose a service that follow the same pattern host//more/paths

the problem is the block location /$sub never gets execute when I try something like GET http://projecta.domain.com/projecta/endpoint

do you have some clue how i can use the variable $sub to du that?

here's an example of the config I did

```
upstream app {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ~^(?P<sub>.+)\.domain.com$;
    root /var/www/static/$sub;

    location /$sub {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Nginx does not support variables in config block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html)

Comment: thanks for the info SALEH